# Spring Boot Rest API won't deploy on Tomcat 8.5.47 with "org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a small Angular 8 app that runs in /ROOT and consumes a Spring Boot Rest API (2 Controller). On my local machine this works out pretty well. On a remote Tomcat 8.5.47 I get an "org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component".
What I've tried so far:
- installing the proper Open JDK (exact the same version that runs on this Tomcat)
- uploading the unzipped project folder (tried unzipping and zipping again as war aswell)
- looking for corrupted jars (doesnt seem so)
- setting File permissions to 755 before unzipping and disabling autodeploy (so i basically only upload the war and set the file permissions before deploying)

pom.xml:

````
```<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.justbender</groupId>
  <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>users</name>
  <url>File:///Users/somedude/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.2.1.RELEASE/backend_logging</url>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>  
    <distributionManagement>
        <site>
            <id>sftp.server</id>
            <name>backend</name>
            <url>somerepo</url>
        </site>
        <repository>
            <id>sftp.server</id>
            <name>backend</name>
            <url>anotherrepo</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>backend</finalName>
  <extensions>
      <extension>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
          <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.4</version>
      </extension>
  </extensions>
 <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

and the Spring boot Controller that my AngularApp consumes:

```
package com.justbender.main.user;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@CrossOrigin(origins="*")
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired   
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, path="/users")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, path="/users")
    void addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userService.save(user);
    }        
}
```
````

What am i missing here ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was logging anything to a superverbose Catalina log that showed me loads of Pages of everything in between

```
26-Feb-2020 14:04:14.508 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/backend]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution`

So I set this property from

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

to

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

And the war deploys without an error.

Answer (score 0):

2.2.4.RELEASE
Spring Boot supports Tomcat 9.0 version, can you try with 9.0 version

Comment: Locally i can and it runs on a Tomcat 9.0 perfectly fine sadly i can't "upgrade" the Remote Tomcat. So to resolve this i have to use a different RELEASE version is that what you're saying ? Thanks for answer anyways !

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-tomcat-8---  try to find the Tomcat information

Comment: Well I've tried setting my parent POM to an earlier RELEASE (2.0.9) which supports Tomcat 8.5.39 (there is no RELEASE for 8.5.47) yet i get the same error. Thanks anyways.